# Add paperclip to mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, mailboxer

I've been using paperclip for a while on my app now.

I recently started to integrate mailboxer and I want to let user attach document to a message.

So far I altered the mailboxer's message table to integrate the paperclip and added the right paperclip fields, but I can't get the file to be saved.

```
class AddAttachmentAttachmentToMailboxerNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :mailboxer_notifications do |t|
      t.attachment :document
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :mailboxer_notifications, :document
  end
end
```

I added the following line in my mailboxer initializer file:

```
Mailboxer::Message.class_eval do
    has_attached_file :document
    validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => ['application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'text/plain', "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
end
```

And then to try saving the document I do:

```
current_user.reply_to_conversation(@conversation, conversation_params[:body], subject = nil, should_untrash = true, sanitize_text = true, conversation_params[:document])
```

I'm not sure what else I should do to make it work.